# Beginner Type Error in Function

Tags: haskell, types

In this function:

```
play :: [Bool] -> ([Bool] -> Bool) -> ([Bool] -> Bool) -> [Bool]
play history agent1 agent2  = history ++ (agent1 history) ++ (agent2 history)
```

Where one of the agents may be:

```
titForTat :: [Bool] -> Bool
titForTat history
    | last history = True
    | otherwise    = False
```

I get the error:

```
    Couldn't match expected type `[Bool]' with actual type `Bool'
    In the return type of a call of `agent1'
    In the first argument of `(++)', namely `(agent1 history)'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely
      `(agent1 history) ++ (agent2 history)'
```

It looks to me that the return type of agent1 should be a list of Booleans, but there seems to be an error. I'm sorry if this is a very beginner question. Thank you

Comment: BTW, your definition of `titForTat` could be reduced to simply:

`titForTat history = last history`

or in pointfree form:

`titForTat = last`

Comment: If your history was stored in reverse order, `titForTat` could be just `titForTat (x:_) = x`.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to store the history as `[(Bool,Bool)]`, so it's easier to see the choices of the agents in every round. And as already suggested, storing the history backwards is more convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(++) expects two lists, but your `agent` functions just return a bool. Try

```
play history agent1 agent2  = history ++ [agent1 history] ++ [agent2 history]
```

If the order in which you store items in your history doesn't matter, using (:) would be more efficient, i.e.

```
play history agent1 agent2  = agent1 history : agent2 history : history
```

Comment: As Frerich says, it would be a really good idea to store the history in reverse order. Not only would it be more efficient, but you could easily define, for example, a function that retaliates only when the other person has defected twice in a row: `titForTwoTats (False:False:_) = True`
`titForTwoTats _ = True`.